# SQL #/count from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT games.*
FROM games 
INNER JOIN invitations ON invitations.game_id = games.id
```

I want to get #(COUNT) of invitations of a game.
I am not sure where to put the count statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the `count()` aggregate function and group by the game id:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, count(i.game_id) TotalInvitations
FROM games g
INNER JOIN invitations i
  ON i.game_id = g.id 
group by g.id, g.name
```

This could also be written using a subquery:

```
select g.*, i.TotalInvitations
FROM games g
INNER JOIN
(
  select game_id, count(game_id) TotalInvitations
  from invitations
  group by game_id
) i
  ON i.game_id = g.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The `count` goes in the `select` clause. It counts all the records at that record's grouping level. Do in order to get a count by games you need to group by `games.id`. If you jsut want a total count then remove `,games.id` from the select clause and don't do any grouping.

```
SELECT count(invitations.invitationID), games.id
FROM games 
INNER JOIN invitations ON invitations.game_id = games.id 
Group By Games.Id
```